# Cannot bind argument to parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How do I get this powershell program to successfully execute?

```
$Source = "\\ahs-bind01\ftptest01\CRAR"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -recurse

 #Declare the file path and sheet name

$file = "C:\Users\us6205\Desktop\DatabaseNameConfigs\Test\CareMoveFileParentDestPaths.xlsx"

$sheetName = "sheet1" 


 #Create an instance of Excel.Application and Open Excel file

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file) 

$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)

$objExcel.Visible=$false 


 #Count max row

$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count 

 #Declare the starting positions

$rowLOC,$colLOC = 1,1
$rowUNC,$colUNC = 1,2 


 #loop to get values and store it 

for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)

{ 

$LOC = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowLOC+$i,$colLOC).text
$UNC = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowUNC+$i,$colUNC).text 

$Path = Get-ChildItem -Path $UNC -recurse |
 Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $true) -and  ( $_.FullName -match "$Source") } 
 $Dest = $Path | New-Item -path $Dest -itemtype directory | Move-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Dest -Force
 }

 #close excel file

$objExcel.quit()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you get any errors upon executing it?

Comment: New-Item: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.  $Dest : + CategoryInfo        InvalidData(:)[New-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException            + FullyQualifiedErrorId: ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed

Comment: I have posted an answer, please check it.

Comment: Yes, the code is already lined up like you suggested. When I copy & pasted into this website, everything got changed around

Answer (score 0):

You want to put these **$Source = "\ahs-bind01\ftptest01\CRAR" Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -recurse** each to its line like this:

```
$Source = "\ahs-bind01\ftptest01\CRAR" 
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -recurse
```

Same with **$rowLOC,$colLOC = 1,1 $rowUNC,$colUNC = 1,2**

```
$rowLOC,$colLOC = 1,1
$rowUNC,$colUNC = 1,2
```

Same with **$LOC = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowLOC+$i,$colLOC).text $UNC = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowUNC+$i,$colUNC).text**

```
$LOC = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowLOC+$i,$colLOC).text 
$UNC = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowUNC+$i,$colUNC).text
```

Also edit **($.PSIsContainer -eq $true) -and ( $.FullName -match "$Source")** to:

```
($_.PSIsContainer -eq $true) -and ( $_.FullName -match "$Source")
```

Comment: Yes, the code is already lined up like you suggested. When I copy & pasted into this website, everything got changed around

Comment: Looks like $UNC = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowUNC+$i,$colUNC).text

$Path = Get-ChildItem -Path $UNC -recurse | Where-Object { ($.PSIsContainer -eq $true) -and ( $.FullName -match "$Source") } returns no values, you have to check excel data on that particular cell and $UNC variable as well.